# How do I know if fastcgi_finish_request() is available?

Tags: php, fastcgi

Is there any approach like:

```
if (extension_loaded('apc') && ini_get('apc.enabled'))
{
echo "APC enabled!";
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test with `function_exists()`:

- [`function_exists` — Return TRUE if the given function has been defined](http://php.net/function_exists)

> Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for function_name […] Returns TRUE if function_name exists and is a function, FALSE otherwise.

Example usage:

```
if (function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
    fastcgi_finish_request();
}
```

Comment: @n0tting I edited within the 5 min grace periodically so no revisions created

Answer (score 1):

`fastcgi_finish_request()` is not a module but a function, to check if you can call it you would do :

```
if (function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
  echo "fastcgi enabled";
}
```